# Touchpad Ubuntu 14.04 starts working after a while

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad

I have a dell inspiron 13-7352, with Synaptics Touchpad I guess. So when  I turn on the computer the touchpad does not work. But it starts working after a while. What is more interesting is that when the touchpad works is cause it's detected as a different device than the Synaptics Touchpad pointer.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06B5:00 06CB:75DB UNKNOWN              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see there's an UNKNOWN device with id=13, that is actually the touchpad. I checked this by enabling or disabling both devices with id=13 and id=15.

Here is also some errors at boot time. They show this famous UNKNOWN device on line number 8.

```
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
886 [   13.001550] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
887 [   13.001551] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
888 [   13.338221] i2c_designware INT3433:00: controller timed out
889 [   13.339029] i2c_hid i2c-DLL06B5:00: failed to retrieve report from device.
890 [   14.339040] i2c_designware INT3433:00: controller timed out
891 [   14.339834] i2c_hid i2c-DLL06B5:00: failed to retrieve report from device.
892 [   14.340435] input: DLL06B5:00 06CB:75DB UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-0/i2c-DLL06B5:00/0018:06CB:75DB.0003/input/input15
893 [   14.340606] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:75DB.0003: input,hidraw1: <UNKNOWN> HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL06B5:00 06CB:75DB] on
894 [   15.339858] i2c_designware INT3433:00: controller timed out
895 [   15.340653] i2c_hid i2c-DLL06B5:00: failed to change power setting.
896 [   16.118293] EXT4-fs (sda8): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
897 [   16.340720] i2c_designware INT3433:00: controller timed out
898 [   16.341564] i2c_hid i2c-DLL06B5:00: failed to set a report to device.
```

I'm really lost and couldn't find any helpful info yet. Any clue you can think of will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just start by saying that I'm pretty new to linux as well, but I was having the same problem with my trackpad on my dell 7352.

I'm running manjaro with i3 DE so I'm not sure how this will work on ubuntu.

After a lot of googling I managed to get my trackpad working. Apparently whats happening is your trackpad is getting stuck in `i2c mode` which I guess isn't supported in your linux kernel, which explains the errors you get on boot-up. The idea is to force your mouse into `ps/2 mode`.

Here is what I did.

This will create the `blacklist.conf` file that you will need to edit (make sure the file doesn't exist already):

```
# checking the files existence (this will list either the file or throw an error
ls -l /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

# if you got an error do this if not skip
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then make sure you have permission to edit by doing:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Now you need to open `blacklist.conf` in whichever text editor you prefer, I used `gedit` so I typed (you can install `gksudo` with `sudo apt-get install gksu`):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following line to the `blacklist.conf` file which should currently be empty:

```
blacklist i2c-hid
```

now save the file and reboot your computer.

After doing all the steps I listed, my trackpad started working. On a side note, I also had trouble with my trackpad not working when I was using elementary OS before. When I first logged in, it wouldn't work but if I closed my laptop and reopened it, the trackpad started working.

Hopefully some of this info helps!

Comment: You might rather use `chmod 644` which would be the proper setting for this file and use then `gksudo gedit ...`. The `gksudo` command can be installed with `sudo apt-get install gksu` if it is not already installed. Cheers